# ORA-00904: "BOOKORDERS": invalid identifier in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, mapping

I have a problem about insert order information into the oracle database.
When I call createOrder funtion in JUnit class, it throws an error as shown below.

```
Hibernate: select ORDERS_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into BOOKORDERS (CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_STATUS, 
ORDER_TOTAL, PAYMENT_METHOD, RECIPIENT_NAME, RECIPIENT_PHONE, 
SHIPPING_ADDRESS, ORDER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into DETAILORDER (quantity, subTotal, book, bookorders) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?)
May 22, 2019 12:26:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
May 22, 2019 12:26:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00904: "BOOKORDERS": invalid identifier
```

How can I fix it?

I can share a relevant codes Order classes with its relevant classes in entity package.

**BookOrders Class**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="BOOKORDERS",catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE")
    public class BookOrders implements Serializable{
    ...

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ORDERS_SEQ", sequenceName="ORDERS_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ORDERS_SEQ")
    @Column(name="ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "pk.bookorders", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        private Set<DetailOrder> orderDetails = new HashSet<DetailOrder>();
    }
```

**Book Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK",catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE"){
        ...

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="BOOK_SEQ", sequenceName="BOOK_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="BOOK_SEQ")
@Column(name="BOOK_ID", nullable = false)
private int id; 

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "pk.book", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DetailOrder> detailOrders = new HashSet<DetailOrder>(); }
```

**Detail Order Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAILORDER", catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.bookorders", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.book", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")) })
public class DetailOrder implements Serializable{

private DetailOrderId pk = new DetailOrderId();

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="DETAIL_ORDER_SEQ", sequenceName="DETAIL_ORDER_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DETAIL_ORDER_SEQ")
    @Column(name="DETAIL_ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private BookOrders bookorders;

    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name="SUBTOTAL")
    private float subTotal;

    @EmbeddedId
    public DetailOrderId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(DetailOrderId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }
}
```

**DetailOrderId Class**

```
@Embeddable
public class DetailOrderId implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private BookOrders bookorders;
}
```

**Test Insert Code**

```
@Test
    public void testCreateOrder() {
        System.out.println("testCreateOrder");
        BookOrders bookorders = new BookOrders();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(42);

        bookorders.setCustomer(customer);
        bookorders.setRecipentName("Recipent Name");
        bookorders.setRecipentPhone("123456789");
        bookorders.setShippingAddress("Address");

        Set<DetailOrder> orderDetails = new HashSet<DetailOrder>();
        DetailOrder detailOrder = new DetailOrder();

        Book book = new Book(24);
        detailOrder.setBook(book);
        detailOrder.setQuantity(1);
        detailOrder.setSubTotal(33.99f);
        detailOrder.setOrders(bookorders);

        orderDetails.add(detailOrder);

        bookorders.setOrderDetails(orderDetails);

        BookOrders savedOrders = ordersDAO.create(bookorders);

        assertNotNull(savedOrders);
        //assertTrue(savedOrders.getId() > 0);


    }
```

Comment: Does the column "BOOKORDERS" exist?

Comment: insert into DETAILORDER (quantity, subTotal, book, **bookorders**) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?) - This seems to be the problem hey.

Comment: Show java code that you run to make inserts

Comment: whenever you want to send a message to an individual person prefix the name with `@` sign such as `@J_D`

Comment: @J_D I edit my post.

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I edit my post

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Ok. How can I fix my error.

Comment: I think the error code implies as if what @J_D suggests...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Could you help me which class throws an error. When I changed the variables , it throws mapping issue.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan bookorders is connected to detailorder with its composite id.

Comment: I don't know not much experienced with java for hands-on projects but it seems `detailOrder.setOrders(bookorders);` should be removed.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan When I remove the code you mentioned, only just first sql code runs rightly. Other sql part related with DETAILORDER cannot work and its values cannot be  inserted into the database. But I want two sql code to run.

Comment: @J_D How can I make a correction in the DETAILORDER class

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I can add <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> in the hibernate.cfg.xml. And I run the code. Two sql codes run perfectly and additional two columns Bookorder and Book in the DetailOrder. These two columns have long raw and raw and have got values. However, Order_ID and Book_ID cannot be set any value (these are null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

DetailOrder Class

```
public class DetailOrder implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "ORDER_ID", column = @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "BOOK_ID", column = @Column(name = "BOOK_ID", nullable = false))})
    private DetailOrderId pk = new DetailOrderId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private BookOrders bookorders;  }
```

DetailOrderId  Class

```
@Embeddable
public class DetailOrderId implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private BookOrders bookorders;
```

BookOrder Class

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "pk.bookorders", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<DetailOrder> orderDetails = new HashSet<DetailOrder>();
```

Book Class

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "pk.book", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<DetailOrder> detailOrders = new HashSet<DetailOrder>();
```